# Python data subset - select value ... from DF1 ... where value exists in DF2

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, subset

I am trying to create a dataframe partly by seeing if values exist in another dataframe. here is the SQL version of what I am trying to do:

```
SELECT *
FROM DF1
WHERE 
Patient_alive='still_alive' 
AND Patient_ID in (SELECT Pat_ID from DF2)
```

Here is the code I am struggling with, the last line is what I can't figure out, i have two versions of pseudocode concerning PT_ID:

```
DF3 = DF1[
        (DF1['Patient_alive'].str.contains('still_alive', case=False))&
        #(DF1['PT_ID'].isin(DF2))
        (DF1['PT_ID'].contains(DF2, case=False))
]
```

Update1:

Input Data of df1:

```
Patient_ID | Patient_Alive | Patient_Name
12345      | StillAlive    | Knowles, Archibald
23456      | NotAlive      | Hauzer, Bruno
911235     | StillAlive    | Samarkand, Samsonite VII
```

Input Data of df2:

```
PT_ID
12345
22222
55555
99999
```

Df3 desired output:

```
Patient_ID | Patient_Alive | Patient_Name
12345      | StillAlive    | Knowles, Archibald
```

Comment: This is a good start. Can you post your sample input data and expected output data? Refer to [MCVE] for more information.

Comment: Since both dataframes share keys, couldn't you just do a join on `Patiend_ID`/`Pat_ID`? Relevant Pandas method: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html

Comment: I have updated samples of df1 and df2. I will attempt the join method as tugayac suggested, otherwise any ideas on how to handle this within the code I started with would be appreciated.

Comment: I too thought a join would be the best way to go here, but if you really want to do it this way perhaps that last line should instead be something like `DF2['PT_ID'].contains(DF1['Patient_ID'])`?

Comment: Instead of contains try `isin()`.

Comment: @7yl4r when I try that i get an error of AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'contains'